# Fill textarea with the bb code in Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm creating a test for the forum and I would like to test the forum BB code. I have a BB code like this,

```
[B][FONT=Trebuchet MS][SIZE=7]Meteor[/SIZE][/FONT][/B]
[COLOR=#000000][FONT=Verdana][I][B][SIZE=4]n: [/B][/I][/FONT]
[S][B][FONT=Verdana]ki[/SIZE][/FONT][/B][/S][/COLOR]
[URL='https:///coral-lps-6/']
[FONT=Impact][SIZE=7][COLOR=#F41600][U]CLICK HERE TO BUY![/U][/COLOR][/SIZE][/FONT][/URL]
```

I'm trying to populate this code in to the text area(wrapped in p tag) using the following way,

```
messageBox = self.browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('.message-editorWrapper p')[0]
code = r"{}".format(bb_code)
self.browser.execute_script("arguments[0].innerHTML = '"+code+"'", messageBox)
```

I'm getting this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "login.py", line 51, in
>   
>       bot.postRequest()   File "login.py", line 31, in postRequest
>       self.browser.execute_script("arguments[0].innerHTML = '"+code+"'", messageBox)   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 636, in execute_script
>       'args': converted_args})['value']   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 321, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py",
>   line 242, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error:
>   Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected
>   token   (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.77)   (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=73.0.3683.68
>   (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72),platform=Linux
>   4.15.0-66-generic x86_64)

But when I use simple text that is working fine. So how I can add the BB CODE in the forum to test that it is working or not using selenimum.

Comment: you put code in `' '` in `innerHTML='...'` but inside BB code you have also `'` in `[URL='https:///coral-lps-6/']` - maybe it makes problem. It can create incorrect JavaScript code. Maybe you should use `" "` in `innerHTML="..."` or in BB code.

Comment: this is useless `r"{}".format(bb_code)` because it add nothing to `bb_code` - it will not add `" "` to code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will guess.

You put code in `' '` in `innerHTML='...'` but inside BB code you have also `'` in `[URL='https:///coral-lps-6/']` and probably it can makes problem. It can create incorrect JavaScript code like

`'code'https:///coral-lps-6/'code'`

which can be treated as three elements

`'code'    https:///coral-lps-6/   'code'`

Maybe you should use `" "` in `innerHTML="..."` or in BB code.

```
js = 'arguments[0].innerHTML = "{}"'.format(code)
```

---

BTW: `r"{}".format(bb_code)` is useless. It change nothing in `bb_code`. And for sure it doesn't add `" "` to `bb_code`. You would need external `' '` to add `" "` - `r'"{}"'.format(bb_code)`

---

**EDIT:** because BB code is in many lines so it may need `\` at the end of lines to inform JavaScript that it is not end of string.

```
bb_code = '''[B][FONT=Trebuchet MS][SIZE=7]Meteor[/SIZE][/FONT][/B]\
[COLOR=#000000][FONT=Verdana][I][B][SIZE=4]n: [/B][/I][/FONT]\
[S][B][FONT=Verdana]ki[/SIZE][/FONT][/B][/S][/COLOR]\
[URL='https:///coral-lps-6/']\
[FONT=Impact][SIZE=7][COLOR=#F41600][U]CLICK HERE TO BUY![/U][/COLOR][/SIZE][/FONT][/URL]'''

js = 'arguments[0].innerHTML = "{}"'.format(bb_code)

print(js)

self.browser.execute_script(js, messageBox)
```

---

**EDIT:** This code works for me. It puts BB code in text area for answer on current page.

```
import selenium.webdriver

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58748338/fill-textarea-with-the-bb-code-in-selenium-python/58748608')

messageBox = driver.find_element_by_id('wmd-input')

bb_code = '''[B][FONT=Trebuchet MS][SIZE=7]Meteor[/SIZE][/FONT][/B]\
[COLOR=#000000][FONT=Verdana][I][B][SIZE=4]n: [/B][/I][/FONT]\
[S][B][FONT=Verdana]ki[/SIZE][/FONT][/B][/S][/COLOR]\
[URL='https:///coral-lps-6/']\
[FONT=Impact][SIZE=7][COLOR=#F41600][U]CLICK HERE TO BUY![/U][/COLOR][/SIZE][/FONT][/URL]'''

js = 'arguments[0].innerHTML = "{}"'.format(bb_code)

#print(js)

driver.execute_script(js, messageBox)
```

Comment: I opened `DevTools` in `Firefox` and put BB code in JavaScript console - if code is in `'  '` (and all in one line) then I get unexpected token but when I put code in `" "` then it works. It treats it as one string. Maybe it has to be in one line

Comment: So where should I change the `'` ? Here? `'arguments[0].innerHTML = "{}"'.format(code)`

Comment: this should create correct code. If you have BB code in many line then put all in one line or use `\`  at the end of line to inform JavaScript that in next line is continuation of current line.

Comment: I edited code and I added `\` in BB code. JavaScript should tread it as inforamtion that it is not end of string. OR even Python should create one line with BB code.

Comment: I added code which I used to put BB code in text area on current page - and for this page it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem was multiple lines and `'` in the BB code. I have fixed that and you are rocks.